# TMemo is painfuly slow when working with large number of lines

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have 100000 lines in a TMemo. I want to do something like:

```
 for i:= 0 to Memo.Lines.Count-1 do
  Memo.Lines[i]:= SomeTrim(Memo.Lines[i]);
```

but the speed is 0.5 lines per second!!

After adding BeginUpdate/EndUpdate I don't see any speed improvement.

```
 Memo.Lines.BeginUpdate;
 for i:= 0 to Memo.Lines.Count-1 do
  Memo.Lines[i]:= SomeTrim(Memo.Lines[i]);
 Memo.Lines.EndUpdate;
```

My question is why BeginUpdate/EndUpdate won't help?

Comment: Poor user who'll be scrolling such memo.

Comment: PS: The current solution is to assign the lines to a TStringList, process them, and put them back into the memo. But I am still curious why BeginUpdate does not work.

Comment: @Victoria - The user will put those lines there. Usually, I expect under 100 lines. I wanted to test to see what happens with 100000. And this is what happens.

Comment: It's a GUI control. It's not designed for text processing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`TStrings.BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` will only prohibit the `OnChanging` and `OnChanged` events. It has no influence on the internal handling of the changes to the content itself.

`TMemo.Lines` is implemented by `TMemoStrings` which stores the text content in the Window control itself. Thus `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` is pretty useless here.

You might get better results by using a local `TStringList` instance, and using the `Text` property to copy the data from `TMemo` to `TStringList` and back. The `Text` property is the most efficient way to access the whole content of a `TMemo` at once.

```
  lst := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lst.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text;
    for I := 0 to lst.Count - 1 do begin
      lst[I] := SomeTrim(lst[I]);
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Text := lst.Text;
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
```

**Note:** Some comments mention to use `Assign` instead of the `Text` property when copying the content from and to the Memo: `Assign` is significantly slower in this case due to an internal optimization of the `Text` property for `TMemoLines`. The Getter and Setter of this property accesses directly the Windows control with a single WM_GETTEXT/WM_SETTEXT message, while `Assign` uses one EM_GETLINE message per line for reading and a sequence of EM_LINEINDEX, EM_SETSEL, EM_LINELENGTH and EM_REPLACESEL per line for writing. A simple timing test shows that the above code needs about 600 ms while replacing the `Text` assignments with `Assign` calls needs more than 11 seconds!

Comment: Use the `Assign()` method instead of the `Text` property: `lst.Assign(Memo1.Lines); ...  Memo1.Lines.Assign(lst);` Since the lines are already separate, just copy them as-is, don't concatenate them just to re-parse them, that is a waste of memory and processing

Comment: @RemyLebeau, getting and setting each line separately is actually what the original code did.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm referring to copying the Memo content to the StringList and then back. Your answer says the `Text` property is the "most efficient" way to do that, but that is not even remotely true, especially for 100000 lines. The `Text` getter performs a 2-pass scan to allocate and copy memory, then the `Text` setter parses the input to perform a LOT of allocatations. `Assign()`, on the other hand, performs far fewer allocations and uses a 1-pass scan. Profile it for yourself, `Assign()` is more efficient than `Text`

Comment: @UweRaabe - Can you give an example where begin/end update makes a difference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, TStrings.Text property uses the virtual GetTextStr and SetTextStr methods, which are overriden in TMemoLines. These implementations access the controls text content through a single WM_GETTTEXT or WM_SETTEXT message call. I tested it and using Text is way faster (like 18x).

Comment: @UweRaabe - Nice to know!!! This applies only to TMemo? Do you know other classes to which this applies too?

Comment: That applies to TMemo and it may as well apply to other classes, although I am currently not aware of any (mostly because I din't investigate yet).

Comment: Uwe is right, see test below.

Answer (score 0):

Test and results:

```
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Conclusion 1:
       BeginUpdate has (a positive) effect ONLY if you add items one by one in a visual control (TMemo, TListBox)

   Conclusion 2:
       If you want to transfer the items from a TStringList to a TMemo, .Text is much faster than .Assign
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}



{ ListBox, adding 10000 items:
  61ms with BeginUpdate 
  1340ms without BeginUpdate }
procedure TfrmMain.btnInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  TimerStart;
  ListBox1.Items.BeginUpdate;
  TRY
    for I := 1 to StrToInt(Edit1.Text) do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(I));
  FINALLY
    ListBox1.Items.EndUpdate;
  END;

  Caption:= 'Inserting: '+ TimerElapsedS;
  Label3.Caption := 'Items : ' + IntToStr(ListBox1.Count);
end;


{ Memo.Lines: 1800ms 
  BeginUpdate makes no difference  }
procedure TfrmMain.btnLinesClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnClearMemoClick(Sender);
  TimerStart;

  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Memo1.Lines := ListBox1.Items;
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;

  Caption:= TimerElapsedS;
end;



{ Memo.Lines.Add: 1900ms 
  BeginUpdate makes no difference }
procedure TfrmMain.btnLinesAddClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnClearMemoClick(Sender);
  TimerStart;
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for VAR I := 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[I])
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
  Caption:= TimerElapsedS;
end;


{ 1900ms | BeginUpdate makes no difference }
procedure TfrmMain.btnAssignClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnClearMemoClick(Sender);
  TimerStart;

  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Assign(ListBox1.Items);
  finally
    Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;

  Caption:= TimerElapsedS;
end;


{ Fill a TStringList and assign it to the Memo }
procedure TfrmMain.btnTSLClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption:= '';

  { 0ms }
  btnClearMemoClick(Sender);
  TimerStart;
  VAR TSL:= TStringList.Create;
  for VAR I := 1 to 10000 do
    TSL.Add(IntToStr(i));
  Caption:= 'Create TSL: '+ TimerElapsedS;

  { TEXT: 64ms with or without BeginUpdate }
  TimerStart;
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  Memo1.Text:= TSL.Text;
  Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  Caption:= Caption+ '.    Text: '+ TimerElapsedS;

  { ASSIGN: 1960ms | BeginUpdate makes no difference }
  btnClearMemoClick(Sender);
  TimerStart;
  Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  Memo1.Lines.Assign(TSL);
  Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  Caption:= Caption+ '.    Assign: '+ TimerElapsedS;

  FreeAndNil(TSL);
end;
```

So, Uwe is right.